# Cocoa NSApp launch automatically after startup / user login

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication

How to create an Helper NSApp that launches after user login?

Doesn't have to be AppStore proof...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have the app launch start at login you just need to call `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` with your bundle ID and bool value.

```
SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.foobar.example", YES) // NO to cancel launch at login
```

You need ServiceManagement framework to access this API.

You can find detailed example [here](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)

Note: This is not a private API so you can use this and submit your apps to App Store.

Comment: Can you use this in sandboxed apps as well?